# Stuck displaying CoreData as cells in Table View

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to display items in my List entity on a table view. I believe my issue is a type casting one, but after researching a bit, I've been unable to find a solution. My exact error is "Cannot assign value of type 'List' to type 'String?'.

Below is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ToBeastViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var items = [List]()


let matthewsManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")

    do {
        let response = try matthewsManagedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)

        print("Sucess!")

        let arrayList = response as! [List]

        for item in arrayList {
            print(item.item)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Failed!")
    } // numberOfRowsInSection end

    return items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

//        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell")! as UITableViewCell

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

//        var itemString = List as! item

    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

The issue is with the line:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
```

...or at least that's my understanding. I apologize if the formatting is poor or if I am missing information that may help. Some of my attempts to solve this are commented out. Thank you for any help!

Edit*

Below is the code from the View that takes text input and adds it to List:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class JustBeastItViewController: UIViewController {

let matthewsManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

//    var items = [List]()


@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("List",  inManagedObjectContext: matthewsManagedObjectContext)
    let newItem = newManagedObject as! List
    newItem.item = justBeastItTextField.text

    do {

        try matthewsManagedObjectContext.save()

        print("It was successful!")

    }
    catch {
        print("There was an error!")
    }

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")

    do {
        let response = try matthewsManagedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)

        print("Sucess!")

        let arrayList = response as! [List]

        for item in arrayList {
            print(item.item)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Failed!")
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var justBeastItTextField: UITextField!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: what is inside of `List`, also the code where you actually fill your data structure should be in `viewDidLoad()`, then  in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should have something like `let data = items[indexPath.row]` then cell.textLabel?.text = `data.whateveryouinList`

Comment: "List" is my Entity and the only attribute is "item". I believe I'm filling the data structure on a button press in a separate view. Would I still need to move that around? The basic concept is that I add items into my List based on text input on the next view. Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of `item`?  If it's a string, you may want `cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row].item`.  If it's not a string, what text do you want to display in the label?

Comment: "item" is listed as "var items: [List]" under declaration. I tried converting this to a string, but that doesn't seem to work. The attribute is originally set to a type of Sting, but I believe that is changed in the other view.